# How to combine these two ffmpeg commands into one with two outputs?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editing

I have some tv series recorded and now I want to cut off the parts before and after the series, remove the corner logo and save it in original size as mkv and also in downscaled size for our mobile car mediaplayer.

At the moment I use these commands to do this job (and these works pretty fine):

```
ComplexFilter="[0:v]trim=start=221.040:end=1660.800,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[outv];[0:a]atrim=start=221.040:end=1660.800,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[outa];[outv]removelogo=mask_corner_logo.png[outv_delogo]"

ffmpeg -y -stats -loglevel warning -i "${SourceFile}" -filter_complex "${ComplexFilter}" -map "[outv_delogo]" -map "[outa]" -c:a libmp3lame -b:a "${AudioBitrate}" "${TargetFile}" </dev/null

ffmpeg -y -stats -loglevel warning -i "${SourceFile}" -filter_complex "${ComplexFilter};[outv_delogo]scale=480:270[outv_scaled]" -map "[outv_scaled]" -map "[outa]" -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k -vcodec mpeg4 -vtag xvid -qscale:v 5 "${AVITargetFile}" </dev/null
```

I am pretty sure it is possible to do these two jobs with one single command.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance,
Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

`ffmpeg -y -stats -loglevel warning -i "${SourceFile}" -filter_complex "${ComplexFilter};[outv_delogo]split=2[outv_delogo][outv_scaled];[outv_scaled]scale=480:270[outv_scaled];[outa]asplit=2[outa1][outa2]" -map "[outv_delogo]" -map "[outa1]" -c:a libmp3lame -b:a "${AudioBitrate}" "${TargetFile}" -map "[outv_scaled]" -map "[outa2]" -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k -vcodec mpeg4 -vtag xvid -qscale:v 5 "${AVITargetFile}" </dev/null`